# Obtain a list of IP Addresses stored as strings. Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily IPv4

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to create a script that gives me a list of IP addresses from the Get-NetNeighbour command. These IP address Strings will be used later on.

Currently I have:

```
Write-Output "Hello World"

#Get Net Neighbours
$netNeighbours = Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily IPv4
#Get the IP address
$listOfIPs = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[String]
foreach ($i in $netNeighbours){
    #Get IP addr from string
    $ipString = Select-Object {$i.IPAddress} | Out-String
    $ipString
    $listOfIPs.Add($ipString)
}

Write-Output $listOfIPs
```

I expect the last line to output a list of strings containing the IP addresses.

`"192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2" etc...`

I instead get this console output:

`Hello World`

Followed by numerous \n characters / blank lines

Any help appreciated

Comment: You're not adding anything to the `$listOfIPs`.  Why not simply do `(Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily IPv4).IPAddress` to get the array of IP addresses ?

Comment: @Theo Apologies I had left in my attempts a t debugging. Corrected now

Comment: Right, but why so difficult? `$listOfIPs = (Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily IPv4).IPAddress` would get you what you want: a string array of IP addresses